# Unity Raycast Event Priority

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use Unity's EventSystem to handle input in my game. I've attached a Physics 2D Raycaster to my camera and objects are receiving the input events such as OnPointerEnter, OnPointerExit etc. However I needed to do something a little more sophisticated with the events. I'd like to assign the input handlers a certain priority to handle the input events.

For example, I created one GameObject with a huge bounding box to catch all mouse clicks. It works fine unless the click happened within another GameObject that can 'intercept' the Raycast. I thought I could fix this by adding multiple Raycasters to my camera that would target multiple layers but it doesn't seem to have worked.

It's a little tricky because if I want one of my objects to do something in OnMouseEnter, it has to intercept all mouse click events as well simply because it has to be a target for the Raycaster. The event methods have a void return type so there's no way to specify whether or not the event was actually handled and that it should "bubble up" to the next handler. The system just seems to depend on the Raycaster and the functionality there seems a little bit lacking. I've hacked a couple things myself and got it mostly working but there are constantly little edge cases that are coming up forcing me to revisit how I'm handling input. I'd like to know if there is a clean way of doing this?

Comment: Something I've done in the past is collect all events during the frame into a list, then sorting that list based on a priority order each `Update()`, handling whatever is on top or in that order or however else you need to handle them.

Also, you shouldn't need more than one raycast. You should be able to get all objects in the raycast and sort those results by priority, no? (I may be misunderstanding the situation.)

Comment: Would changing execution order help? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html Or child position in the overall heirarchy?

Comment: @BJennings Yea that's what I've been doing but I ran into into this issue where none of my smaller objects would receive OnPointerEnter/Exit because I had one big catch all object (for clicks) that would eat that event. Also, there is an area around the player that needs to listen for OnPointerEnter, and I believe that would eat the OnPointerEnter for objects within that area.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you want to get objects that are below those event-absorbing objects, then It sounds like a raycast that collects all objects under the cursor and then sorts them according to your needs when the event occurs sounds like the way to go